# Oledb Parameter in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am inserting data from vb.net to oracle but I am unable to insert datetime except date into oracle.  I want to insert date and also time of entry into database:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(":STARTING_DATE", (OleDb.OleDbType.[Date].))
cmd.Parameters(":STARTING_DATE").Value = DateTime.Now()
cmd.Parameters(":STARTING_DATE").Value = txtStartDate.Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmd.Parameters.Add(":STARTING_DATE", (OleDb.OleDbType.[DBTimeStamp].))

apparently.

More info here

[MSDN OleDb.OleDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype.aspx)